# After dissolve join many to one

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap

Using ArcMap 10.3, I have a shapefile with dissolved roads and I have 10 records with the Road ID field (they are all unique). I want to join an Excel file with Road-ID with 15 records and I want to append Geometry. for example:
[image]

So I want to have Road ID 10  with values 5 and 10 after join in the dissolved layer.

I guess it is  Many to one join. So Actually I want to copy the record, 2 times in case Road Id 10 is two times in the Excel file and so on. Right join is not working, here.

Should I use iterators?

Comment: So are you asking to create a dataset where the geometry is duplicated also? If so I would say that is not the right way of doing things. Explore the help file and research "relates".

Comment: I updated my comment, I tried "relates" but not helping too much. So in the end I want to have line with 15 records as it is in excel file. It means for some Road_iD it will be duplicated lines.

Comment: I joined, but copy to a new feature class- asks to use feature class with geometries.

Comment: You are better off putting the second values into a second column. Duplicating features is in no way helpfull!